# Email API authorized senders

Tags: google-app-engine

I want to send emails using python on GAE, so edited "Email API authorized senders" in:

```
https://console.developers.google.com/project/MY_PROJECT/appengine/settings
```

under "Email API authorized senders", I added `support@mydomain.com` (where `mydomain.com` is registered via google domain, and linked to MY_PROJECT)

I got a message saying I don't have enough privilege to make this change. Any idea why? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/?hl=en_US#Java_Sending_mail) says

> All email addresses on the Email API Authorized Senders list need to
>   be valid Gmail or Google-hosted domain Accounts. There are
>   restrictions on who can add whom to the Email API Authorized Senders
>   list:
>
> - Application administrators can add themselves
> - Application administrators for applications hosted in a Google Apps domain can add
>     noreply@domain.com, as long as noreply@domain.com is a valid account
> - Domain administrators of domains managed by Google Apps can add any
>     user in their domain

So you would need to be a Google Apps admin and the *user* you're trying to add must also exist in Google Apps. Sadly the documenation doesn't mention *groups* in the Apps domain which would be quite useful.

Comment: I hope they didn't drop this. I have GAE apps that use Google groups (noreply@domain.com) as email sender when sending emails. I'm pretty sure this feature was documented in the section you quoted. Sending emails with Google groups' email addresses still works though.

Comment: Thanks @konqi. Maybe i misunderstood the documentation, but the email i'm trying to add is a valid  Google-hosted domain Account though. I registered the domain name via google domain.

Comment: @Ani that's good to know. I'm also pretty sure that i've done that myself before.The dialog for entering *Email API Authorized Senders* is new to me though. I'm not sure how long it even exists.

Comment: @KellyL It should not matter at which registrar you registered your domain. According to the documentation it has to be a Google Apps domain though. I'm not convinced that is true. You could try to add the domain as custom domain to your app via https://console.developers.google.com/project/you-app-id/appengine/settings/domains and see if that helps.

Comment: I was able to add my non-google domain as email sender (just like before years ago) 1. first add this email as admin from IAM, and it will invite
2. This email must have google account. I think i've made mine with youtube years ago, but don't have gmail. After accept and login (logout with original admin first fully!) go to gae > settings > email.. and add works! yeasss!