# Criteria for Authorized Senders in Google App Engine

Tags: python, email, google-app-engine

To start, neither of these two stackoverflow pages answer my question ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33008267/email-api-authorized-senders), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621019/google-appengine-sending-emails-error-unauthorized-sender)). One of them should actually be removed as the text it's quoting appears to be out of date.

The Doc on the topic says as follows ([3](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/)):

> For security purposes, the sender address of a message must be one of the following:
>
> - The Gmail or Google Apps Account of the user who is currently signed in
> - Any email address of the form anything@appname.appspotmail.com or anything@appalias.appspotmail.com
> - Any email address listed in the Cloud Platform Console under Email API Authorized Senders

I tried adding variants of anything@appname.appspotmail.com to the Authorized Senders list and they all fail. Hence, my questions are:

1. What qualifies as appname or appalias? (I tried the "Project Name" in the Project Information page in the console)
2. (realized this right now) Do emails fitting this syntax even have to be entered into the Authorized Senders list or are they just assumed (where "assumed" means I can always use them as the sender address in emails I create in the GAE)?

I now expect 2) to be the case, but I think it might be useful if this ambiguity in the documentation is cleared up.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For #1:

- The `appname` is the app's ID.
- The `appalias` is the app ID of a migrated app (created automatically
  during migration of old master-slave apps to HRD, for example, see
  [Deleting a Google App Engine alias app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11941558/deleting-a-google-app-engine-alias-app)).

For #2 - you're right (the 2nd bullet the doc quote wouldn't make sense otherwise since it'd be covered by the 3rd bullet)

BTW, you can always use the `Send feedback` link in the top(-ish) right side of a documentation page to... well... send feedback on that page.